# MarkupExtension, IValueConverter Defaul Constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, markup-extensions

I'm confused why I need the default constructor in this use case.

```
<Button Name="RemoveWord" IsEnabled="{Binding SearchText.Length, Converter={aw:CountToBoolConverter CountToBoolConverter}, ElementName=WordForAction }" />
```

and my converter is

```
public class CountToBoolConverter : MarkupExtension,  IValueConverter
{
    public CountToBoolConverter(string value)
    {

    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool enabled = (int)value > 0;
        return enabled;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

What is the default constructor used for in this case and how do I know what parameters it expects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MarkupExtension needs a constructor with string parameter (which is not a default constructor) because you added an unnecessary string to the XAML expression that creates the converter:

```
Converter={aw:CountToBoolConverter CountToBoolConverter}
```

The second `CountToBoolConverter` string here is pointless and the expression should just be

```
Converter={aw:CountToBoolConverter}
```